# Detect clickable areas within <img> tag in Ionic project

Tags: html, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ui-automation

I have static image like below, within image various buttons are there like Main,F1, F2 etc., need to make those buttons clickable and call api.
In what all ways we can achieve this scenario's, any leads would be very helpful.[image]

Comment: One approach you can try is template matching.  You can read more at https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html .

Comment: It would be easy to understand the requirement if you can add the images.

Comment: Yeah added image and I will try to implement template matching in JavaScript, Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: image processing requires accurate images. I strongly doubt that your real GUI looks like the drawing you made. the layout may be the same but not the look.

Comment: Hi @Christoph Rackwitz, Thank you for responding. 
I have uploaded actual image for the reference

Comment: is this for *making a GUI*? where is this picture from? is this from a HTML page? is there a `<map>` tag accompanying the image?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: Stop over engineering things. KISS!!! Just create the html/css needed.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to not use an image. it would be better to do your buttons in HTML and style them as you wish. You could also create the buttons in HTML and set the background of the button, as an image.

if you really want to use this image, you should create some button, make them transparent with CSS and place them (maybe with absolute position) over the image in the corrisponding spots

**Edit** (thanks *Christoph Rackwitz*):

probably the best solution would be to use the `<map>` tag: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

> The  tag is used to define an image map. An image map is an image with clickable areas.

Comment: recommend reading up on the `<map>` tag

Comment: this question is STILL not clear.

Comment: idk, as stated in my answer I would not use an image, but in the question he talks about a static image, so I guess he actually want to use this image and make it clickable.

Comment: to me it sounds like it's already clickable, but he doesn't know where to click (don't mind my edits to his question's title, I'm guessing too). anyway, as long as OP plays possum, we can't do anything but hang a balloon and drive on.

Comment: Thank you editing the question @ChristophRackwitz and it make more understandable now. So Basically, we have static image, within the image it consist of buttons like Main, F1, F2 etc, I need make those buttons clickable in more dynamic way. 

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: @SachinKm does `<map>` answer your question? or we more details why `<map>` won't work for you. Maybe edit your original question adding details.

Comment: @Zerotwelve <map> working fine for me, looking for more dynamic solution.
In sometime I will edit the question correctly.

Comment: And also yours and @ChristophRackwitz answer gave some idea to continue the work on that.